# UITableView scroll to top when tapping status bar at top of the screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I inserted a `UITableView` inside another `UIViewController`'s view.
but when I tap the status bar at the top of the screen; the table view doesn't scroll to the top which is the expected behavior within iOS apps.

I tried :

```
[self.tableView setScrollsToTop:YES];
```

but the tableview still not scroll to top when tap the top of the screen.

Comment: Do you have multiple scroll views on screen?  (A `UITableView` is a scroll view.  So is a `UITextView`.)

Comment: i have uiviewcontroller which contains multiple views, one of them is UITableView, but when i tap the top of the screen, this UITableView doesn't scroll to top, is there notification message sent from top bar when the user tapping it?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Do you have **multiple** scroll views on screen?  Keep in mind that `UITextView` is also a scroll view.

Comment: BTW, there is no public notification when the status bar is tapped.

Comment: i don't have multiple scroll views, this tableview only is the scroll.

Comment: sorry, there are other UItableViews in the background

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You have to set `scrollsToTop` to `NO` on all the other scroll views in your hierarchy.  If more than one scroll view has `scrollsToTop` set to `YES`, none of them will scroll to top when the status bar is touched.  This is mentioned in the documentation of the `scrollsToTop` property.

Keep in mind that this also applies to any subclasses of `UIScrollView` in your view hierarchy, and that `UITableView`, `UIContainerView`, and `UITextView` are subclasses of `UIScrollView`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all,
i resolved this problem by removing all other UITableView from the parent ViewController, and then auto scroll to top was working for this UITableView..

thanks