# scrollsToTop not working for simple Master-Detail iOS Application

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

Using Xcode 4.6.1, iOS SDK 6.1, creating a new Master-Detail iOS application (with ARC, no storyboards) and in the DetailViewController I make configureView as:

```
- (void)configureView
{
    UITableView *lTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    lTableView.scrollsToTop = YES;  // just to emphasise, it is the default anyway
    lTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: lTableView];
}
```

Then I make sure there is enough data in the UITableView by returning 100 dummy UITableViewCells, it seems a tap on the status bar does not scroll the table view to the top.

What is the obvious thing I am missing here?

Comment: Try after setting this -> lTableView.delegate = self;

Comment: Hi Bala. Tried it, doesn't help.

Comment: Do you have More than one Scrollviews in your DetailView ?

Comment: If you have more than one scrollviews in your DetailView then this might help you - > http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960080/1059705

Comment: See answer by @jszumski below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll to top of UITableView by tapping status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165913/scroll-to-top-of-uitableview-by-tapping-status-bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrolling to the top of the view won't work if any other `UIScrollView` instance or subclass instance in the same window also has `scrollsToTop` set to `YES` because iOS doesn't know how to choose which one should scroll.  In your case, `configureView` is actually called twice:

- In `viewDidLoad` when the detail controller is loaded
- In `setDetailItem:` when the master controller pushes to the detail controller

Because you're adding a `UITableView` as a subview in `configureView`, you end up with two table views, both with `scrollsToTop` set to `YES`.  To fix the issue, create the table view in `viewDidLoad` and only use `configureView` to modify the base state as required for a given detail item.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITableView *lTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    lTableView.scrollsToTop = YES;
    lTableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: lTableView];

    [self configureView];
}
```

Comment: There is a follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974893/scrollstotop-not-working-with-uiviewcontroller-containment   which is closer to the actual problem I'm after, and on which I'm a bit stuck as well. Any help much appreciated.