# scrollsToTop not working with UIViewController containment

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

Using SDK 6.1, Xcode 4.6.1, I make a new project Master-Detail iOS App, ARC, no storyboards.

Then in the `DetailViewController`, in the `viewDidLoad` I add two `UITableView`s contained in `UIViewController`s and make sure the second one is hidden like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *lViewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *lTableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    lTableView1.scrollsToTop = YES;
    [lViewController1.view addSubview: lTableView1];
    lTableView1.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: lViewController1.view];
    [self addChildViewController: lViewController1];

    UIViewController *lViewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *lTableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    lTableView2.scrollsToTop = YES;
    [lViewController2.view addSubview: lTableView2];
    lTableView2.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: lViewController2.view];
    [self addChildViewController: lViewController2];

    // now hide the view in view controller 2
    lViewController2.view.hidden = YES;
}
```

(I make sure the `DetailViewController` is a datasource that returns 100 rows of `UITableViewCell`s with the `textLabel.text` set to `@"hello"`)

The presence of the second view controller makes that `scrollsToTop` (tapping on the status bar) does not work anymore. If I do not use `UIViewController` containment and just add two `UITableView`s and set the second one to be hidden, `scrollsToTop` does work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Download project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/165243/TestScrollsToTop.zip

Comment: I would guess the Apple code does not check whether a view is hidden when it searches for views that have 'scrollsToTop'. Is there a reason  that you use 'hidden' instead of removing/adding the subview(s) to the superview?

Comment: It does check. If you don't use view controller containment it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently experimenting with your project. When

```
lViewController2.view.hidden = YES;
```

is replaced with

```
lTableView2.hidden = YES;
```

then the scrolling works, even with controller containment.

I tried to insert a view between the controller's view and the table and then hide this view, but the table was not scrolling.

I tried to hide the controller by experimenting with `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` but the table was not scrolling.

**Result:** From my experiments, only one scroll view must be visible in the view hierarchy and the `hidden` property of the parent views is not checked out. `hidden` must be set to `NO` on all other scroll views, not their parent views.

Comment: This is what I overlooked so far I guess: the hidden property of the parent views is not checked out. By using view controller containment I added an extra level in the view hierarchy and changed the hidden property of the parent view instead of the table view. I guess Apple could document this better (if it's not a bug).

Comment: Nice one – I was using the "hidden scroll view that doesn't even contain its own gesture recognisers, and it simply used to scroll other content" technique, and was getting this issue because I'd hidden it.

Answer (score 8):

`scrollsToTop` only works on a single visible view. From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html):

> This gesture works on a single visible scroll view; if there are multiple scroll views (for example, a date picker) with this property set, or if the delegate returns `NO` in `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:`, `UIScrollView` ignores the request. After the scroll view scrolls to the top of the content view, it sends the delegate a `scrollViewDidScrollToTop:` message.

You could try calling `[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]` on each of your table (or scroll) views manually instead.  To do this, implement the `scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:` method in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol:

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [lTableView1 setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
    [lTableView2 setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: There **is** only a single visible scroll view (see last line of the code in viewDidLoad).

Comment: Put a downloadable archive on my dropbox: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/165243/TestScrollsToTop.zip

Comment: I assumed you were setting `hidden` to `NO` before the scrolling to top event.

Comment: Anyway, tried your test project on Xcode 4.6.1 + iOS SDK 6.1 on both the simulator and an iPhone 4, and both approaches you have there work.

Comment: Did you look at the Detail View? The Master view works, but the Detail View doesn't. (verified and double checked with my colleague)

Answer (score 4):

You can only set ***1* ScrollView** per ViewController with property .scrollsToTop = YES.
If you set 2 scrollview.scrollsTopTop = YES, it will simply stop functioning.

```
ie: your sample project (DetailViewController.m) update following lines,

line48:    lTableView1.scrollsToTop = YES; 
line56:    lTableView2.scrollsToTop = NO;
```

then, scrollsToTop works correctly. If there are more than 1 scrollview you wish to concurrently setScrollsToTop, keep digging around. good luck!

Comment: Except when one of the tableviews is hidden, then they can have both scrollsToTop to YES. **Except if you use view controller containment**, then it does not work anymore, and that's the question I am seeking an answer to.

Comment: you can have it setHidden:, removeFromSuperView or setScrollsToTop:No, as long as *only* 1 scrollView is set responding to ScrollsToTop: scrolling event.

Comment: Download the sample code and you'll see that *not using view controller containment* (put the define VIEW_CONTROLLERS in DetailViewController to 0) there is no problem with having two scrollsToTop table views.

Answer (score 0):

After testing several options and various hits and try I finally settled to one final solution, i.e. `setBounds:` of `scrollView` (that is `tableView` in your case) and it works good. You'll have to put extra effort for animation although.

```
    CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollView setBounds:frame];
```

By the way in your case, try returning `YES` to

```
- (BOOL)scrollViewShouldScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Although if not defined, assumes YES.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your answer. Are you suggesting a custom implementation of scrollsToTop?

Comment: OK, but in my project that is not an option and neither is it an answer to the question. Thanks though :)

Comment: I'm asking this question for a bug in an existing project that is in the market and we want to minimise the changes to existing versions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this and now it works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIViewController *lViewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *lTableView1 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    lTableView1.scrollsToTop = YES;
    [lViewController1.view addSubview: lTableView1];
    lTableView1.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: lViewController1.view];
    [self addChildViewController: lViewController1];
    lTableView1.tag=1;

    UIViewController *lViewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UITableView *lTableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.frame];
    lTableView2.scrollsToTop = NO;
    [lViewController2.view addSubview: lTableView2];
    lTableView2.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: lViewController2.view];
    [self addChildViewController: lViewController2];
    lTableView2.tag=2;
    // now hide the view in view controller 2
    lViewController2.view.hidden = YES;

}

- (NSUInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSUInteger)section {
    return 50;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath {
    static NSString * const kCellIdentifier = @"MyCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kCellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello %d %d",indexPath.row, tableView.tag];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: So you're just changing one scrollsToTop property? That's not the answer I was looking for (Sulthan's answer has been accepted in the mean time).